# Googlefit API integration to fetch user profile

Tags: php

I want top retrieve the user profile information from Googlefit using goggleapi. But i didnt find any url endpoint to the user profile.Please anyone can suggest how to retrieve the profile?

Answer (score 0):

Instead set the scope of user plus profile and user.info while requesting access code and with that you will be able to get user info.

Comment: I already given these scopes "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.profile https://www.googleapis.com/auth/fitness.activity.read https://www.googleapis.com/auth/fitness.activity.write https://www.googleapis.com/auth/fitness.body.read https://www.googleapis.com/auth/fitness.body.write https://www.googleapis.com/auth/fitness.location.read https://www.googleapis.com/auth/fitness.location.write" But i didnt find a url end poitn to fetch the user profile like in gplus as "https://www.googleapis.com/plus/v1/people/me/?access_token={YOUR_ACCESS_TOKEN}.

Comment: Use https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email     as another scope to get the email